# OpenCSV: Is it possible to use BindByName + BindByPosition combo, but only for a few columns?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have large csv with several columns with duplicated names, e.g.:

```csv
name;surname;status;fullname;status;
John;Doe;Active;John Doe;Married;
```

And I'd like to map columns only by names but since there are duplicates I probably need to use `@BindByPosition` as well. So my class would look like this:

```java
@BindByName("name")
String name;

@BindByName("surname")
String surname;

@BindByName("status")
@BindByPosition(2)
String workStatus;

@BindByName("fullname")
String fullname;

@BindByName("status")
@BindByPosition(4)
String maritialStatus;
```

But it won't work, it'll only map both "statuses" and leave other fields empty. Is there a way to use position only for those two columns?
In my real code I have 130 columns and filling positions for all of them would be a nightmare - especially because the order will change in the future.

But maybe there is some other way of dealing with duplicated column names?

Comment: `duplicated column names` and `order will change in the future` will eventually break thing even if you can implement what you want. 
So I would suggest 1. write some script so you can generate the pojo with `BindByPosition` 2. resolve duplicate in the header before processing.

Comment: I went with the second proposition and resolved duplicates in the header before processing. Thanks!